# Increment telerik progress bar with unknown number of items

Tags: telerik, progress-bar

I have a process where users can upload a file and have it processes.
My windows forms application takes the number rows and processes them but I want the progress bar to follow along with the number of rows that are processed.

For example.
Say someone uses a file with 51 rows.  So what I do is divided 100 by the 51 and I get 1.96078431372549.  Now the progress bar only takes in integers so a double won't work.  If I round up when I get to the 51 row the progress bar will error out because the number will be above 100.

What would be the best way to handle this situation?  Especially since the users files can have from 50 to 100,000 rows.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already checked the [Custom Progress demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/progressarea/examples/customprogress/defaultcs.aspx) on the telerik site.

Looking at the code of the ProgressData class in JustDecompile, it looks like all of the following properties are of type object, so you can pass a decimal here:
PrimaryTotal, PrimaryValue, PrimaryPercent, SecondaryTotal, SecondaryValue, SecondaryPercent.

So you just need to make sure the percentage is no bigger than 100.
Try removing the percentage and see if everything else works as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I actually just redid the way I'm doing it this morning.  I just took what the count of rows was in the file and make that my max value and then incremented the progress bar by one every time it looped.  I don't display the percentage so it seems to work good.   Thank you